# What are the best practices for resolving jpa bidirectional circular references?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, backend

What are the best practices for resolving JPA bidirectional circular references?

I experienced an error falling into infinite recursion due to JPA bidirectional circular reference.

At this time, it was said that the problem could be solved in the following way.

1. Ignore using `@JsonIgnore`
   -> I ruled out this option because I need all the data.
2. Use `@JsonBackReference`, `@JsonManagedReference`.
   -> Currently, I have solved my problem using this method.

I'm wondering if there's a better way to solve the problem, so I'm leaving a question like this.

best regards!

Comment: 3. dont use bidirectional references. I think that is the easiest one

Comment: @Antoniossss bi-directional mappings are better for performance with Hibernate

Comment: @SimonMartinelli any quotations/referenes on that ?

Comment: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: It only states that depending on relation configuration you can either fallback to lazy or eager fetch mode which can be set to lazy anyway on unidirectional relationship, therfore it is not related.

Comment: Sorry wrong link: https://vladmihalcea.com/high-performance-java-persistence-chapter-11-relationships/

Comment: This is a summary of some book which I dont have, but my best bet is that conclusion will be the the same as it is the same author.

Comment: @Antoniossss Vlad is a Hibernate expert and former Hibernate commiter. And he knows all the interals of Hibernate. So you can trust him

Comment: @SimonMartinelli sure, but I didnt find anything that supports your claims in Vlads materials you have quoted - that defining bidirectional relationships directly improves performance.  As I wrote, I think this might be default behavior beeing LAZY in case of using particular set of annotations which probably happens to be the case when u define bidirectional relationships.

Comment: It's only in the book chapter 11.3.4. Unidirectional mappings without JoinColum add extra inserts for the relationship table and with JoinColumn it adds extra update statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference` are semantically correct.

`@JsonIngore` not.

Checkout this article: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "property1","property2" })` just above a field, to ignore some properties nested inside this field. So you will get the field itself with its nested properties, except the nested properties specified in `@JsonIgnoreProperties`.

This solution prevent the infinite recursion, but enable you to get the nested entity you need.

I found this solution after reading [this](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2940), supposing that if it was asked for a `@JsonIgnoreProperties` solution for two levels of nested properties, it was already possible to use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` for just one level of nested properties.

Answer (score -1):

your case object is calling inner object and inner object calling object so,Remove getter methods from inner object(one side). i think it works.

Comment: But this doesn't make sense

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).